# Obligar a poner un comentario cuando se hace una validación de datos

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy haciendo una validación de datos en la Hoja de Cálculo de Google y estoy intentando hacer que cuando seleccionen un dato con el desplegable te obligue a poner un comentario, esto se puede hacer? Estoy buscando como hacerlo pero no lo consigo.

Seria algo como seleccionar una opción de esta lista:

[image]

Y cuando se seleccionara por ejemplo el 301 que te obligue a poner un comentario en esa celda.

Comment: De acuerdo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior las publicaciones no deben incluir saludos, despedidas, firmas ni otra cosa mas que el contenido propio de la consulta que se está realizando.

Answer (score 1):

Las Hojas de Cálculo de Google no incluyen una función para obligar el insertar un comentario. Podrías usar una secuencia de comandos (script) de Google Apps Script que sea ejecutada mediante un activador (trigger) al editar o al modificar para realizar algunas acciones al modificar el valor de una celda. Por ejemplo, podrías mostrar un diálogo de entrada de datos y agregarlo como una nota de celda.

Nota: Actualmente con Google Apps Script no es posible insertar un comentario como el de menú Insertar > Comentario que sea asociado a una celda en particular.